# minimum number of groups required

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-coloring

Can anyone please help me with the best approach for the below-mentioned problem?

> Let's say there are n children. These children need to be divided into
> groups. But, the issue is there are some pairs m of children who don't
> want to go in same group. Can you tell the minimum number of groups we
> have to form?
>
> Input Description:
>
> First line will contain two non-negative integers n and m.  Then next
> m lines will contain two non-negative integers which are the given
> pairs of children.

```
Input:
6 3
1 4
2 3
1 5

Output
2.

Explanation:
(1,2,6), (3,4,5) can be two groups which satisfy all the given conditions.
```

I see that this can be solved by converting it into a graph with edges between given pair of numbers and finding the chromatic number of it. Looking for better solutions than this.

Comment: Better in what way?

Comment: This problem is **literally** asking to output the chromatic number of the graph given in input. There is no need to "convert" anything.

Answer (score 1):

This is the optimization variant of [Vertex Coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring).

This problem is a known NP Complete problem (except for 2 coloring), so there is no known efficient solution to this problem for large graphs. For small graphs, you could try backtracking and/or branch& bound solutions.